# oneliner for zippping list and dict

Tags: ansible

1 list as key and other entire list as value for each key in a dict

I am using Ansible 2.7

I Have the following two lists.

```
list1:
  -  l1
  -  l2
  -  l3
  -  l4
  -  l5
  -  l6

list2:
  -  L1
  -  L2
```

when i use `"{{dict(list1 | zip(list2))}}"`
I am getting the following output

```
l1: L1
l2: L2
```

However I expect the following output using single liner in Ansible.

```
l1: [L1, L2]
l2: [L1, L2]
l3: [L1, L2]
l4: [L1, L2]
l5: [L1, L2]
l6: [L1, L2]
```

Can someone please help me with the one liner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was like a puzzle problem for me.
Think I have found a one-liner for that.
Maybe somebody will have a better proposal!

```
"{{ dict(list1 | zip_longest([list2], fillvalue=list2)) }}"
```

### Explanation

The idea is to use `zip` to zip the first list (`list1`) with a `list` of `list2` (`[list2]`). So the `zip` will aggregate `list1` with `list2` instead of taking each element of `list2`.
But in this case you will end with one good item and the other will not be correct since the lists are not (obviously) of the same size (the second has a size of one). In this case the solution is to use `zip_longest` instead of `zip` in order to use `list2` when there is no more element to zip. Check [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) documentation for information on Ansible filters.

### Full playbook

```
---
- name: Oneliner for zippping list and dict
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    list1:
      -  l1
      -  l2
      -  l3
      -  l4
      -  l5
      -  l6
    list2:
      -  L1
      -  L2

  tasks:
    - name: Perform a command that will not be understood without a good comment ...
      set_fact:
        result: "{{ dict(list1 | zip_longest([list2], fillvalue=list2)) }}"
    - name: Print result
      debug:
        var: result

# ok: [localhost] => {
#     "result": {
#         "l1": [
#             "L1",
#             "L2"
#         ],
#         "l2": [
#             "L1",
#             "L2"
#         ],
# [...]
```

### Disclaimer

I'm not sure it's a good idea to use that. I will prefer a more explicit and standard way of doing it like in the answer proposed by @Matt P.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be a one-liner? This will achieve your desired outcome:

```
    - set_fact:
        new_dict: {}

    - set_fact:
        new_dict: "{{ new_dict | combine({item: list2}) }}"
      loop: "{{ list1 }}"
```

Comment: set_fact in a loop will display item labels for each item. Even if I control the label usong loop_control, i will still get ths iterated items in playbook output. However if I use oneliner in vars: then the output will be neater. Consider the case where I have 10k items in list1. It will show 10k lines in playbook output.